# docker-compose using old volumes

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, volumes

I am trying to set up a CI pipeline with docker-compose and am struggling to understand how named volumes work...

As part of my Dockerfile, I copy in the application files and then run `composer install` to install the application dependencies. There are some elements of the applicaton files and the dependencies that I want to share with the other containers that are running / are set up to be run to perform utility processes (such as running database migrations). See the example below:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

# Install dependencies
COPY composer.* /app/
RUN composer install --no-dev

# Copy application files
COPY bin bin
COPY environment.json environment.json

VOLUME /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
 web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - app:/app
      - ~/.cache/composer:/composer/cache

  migrations:
    image: my-image
    depends_on:
      - web
    environment:
      - DB_DRIVER=pdo_mysql
      - AUTOLOADER=../../../vendor/autoload.php
    volumes:
      - app:/app
    working_dir: /app/vendor/me/my-lib

volumes:  
  app:
```

In the example above (irrelevant information omitted), I have a "migrations" service that pulls the migrations from the application dependencies installed with composer. My idea is that when I perform `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`, it will bring up the latest version of software with the latest dependencies and run the latest migrations at the same time.

This works fine the first time. Unfortunately on subsequent runs I cannot get docker-compose to use the new versions. If I run `docker-compose build`, I can see the `composer install` run and install all the latest libraries, but then when I go into the container with `docker-compose run web /bin/bash`, the old dependencies are in there! If I run the image directly with `docker run web_1`, I can see all the latest files no problem. So it's definitely a compose-specific problem.

I assume I need to do something like clear out the volume cache, but whatever I have tried doesn't seem to work. I can only assume I am misunderstanding the idea of volumes.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here has to do with mounting a volume over a location defined in the build. The first build of the image has `composer` put its output into `/app`, and the first run of the first build mounts the `app` named volume to `/app`. This clobbers the image version of `/app` with a new write-layer on top. Mounting this named volume on the second build of the image will keep the original contents of `/app`.

Instead of using a named volume, use `volumes-from` to load the exported `/app` volume from `web` into the `migration` container.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/.cache/composer:/composer/cache
  migrations:
    image: docker-registry.efficio.digital:5043/doctrine-migrator:1.1
    depends_on:
      - web
    environment:
      - DB_DRIVER=pdo_mysql
      - AUTOLOADER=../../../vendor/autoload.php
    volumes_from:
      - web:ro
```

Comment: No, I understood those commands exactly as you epzlaiebd 
a them. Sorry, i  probably didn't explain very well.  I know build won't do anything about migrations. Forget migrations for the moment, my problem is that when I docker compose up the web container it has the files from a previous build in it, even though, as you can see in my dockerfile, the dependencies are installed on build. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm saying that when you are using `docker-compose run`, you are still using the _old container_ and the _old image_. You need to stop and remove the old container, and start a new container with the new image to get the updated dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I am doing that. That's what's perplexing me is that even on the second run after a SECOND BUILD I get the OLD files (from the first build). Even if I remove the image between builds. And it's only with compose;. Ifse `docker run /bin/bash`, I can see the correct files. If use `docker-compose run /bin/bash`, I can see a totally different set of files. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I still understand. When you are using `docker-compose run` it is _not_ using the new image. Because you already created a container with the old image. Have you tried running `docker-compose down` before running `docker-compose run` again?

Comment: Yes I have. I have ran `docker compose down`, `docker compose rm`, removed the image, removed all volumes and ran `docker system prune`. Then if ran `build` again, then `run` again, and I get the old files from the first build.

Comment: Ok, I'm noticing something else here. You are using `composer` during the build in the `/app` directory, but then attaching a volume to `/app`. Volumes are not available during builds.

Comment: Ah okay, but it's a named volume? I thought that only applied to volumes from the host. So you're saying if I run composer install during build and then up the container, the old volume that is stored somewhere will overwrite the files on up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152570/discussion-between-wmorrell-and-raiden616).

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is you want to run composer install every time you run your container. In that case you have to use CMD instruction to execute that command.

CMD composer install --no-dev

RUN and CMD are both Dockerfile instructions.

RUN lets you execute commands inside of your Docker image. These commands get executed once at build time and get written into your Docker image as a new layer.

For example if you wanted to install a package or create a directory inside of your Docker image then RUN will be what you’ll want to use. For example, RUN mkdir -p /path/to/folder.

CMD lets you define a default command to run when your container starts.

You could say that CMD is a Docker run-time operation, meaning it’s not something that gets executed at build time. It happens when you run an image. A running image is called a container.

Comment: No, that's not remotely what I want to do. Composer is ran as part of the build, as you can see from my dockerfile. The problem is that even when I run docker compose build first, when I run up the container contains files from an old build, even though I can see the new files being installed during the dokcer compose build process.